# English version of my site show french strings

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml

This is a weird one :

http://www.famille-labruyere.com/ is the french version of the site
http://www.famille-labruyere.com/en/ is the english one

The problem is that the english version show theme strings in french.

I have no idea why.

Infos : i use WPML and the network of websites wordpress features.

Comment: Have you translated these theme strings? Is the theme you're using already translated? Is it prepared for translation?

Comment: Yes to all. Theme is activated, the .po and .mo files are there and I use the correct functions __() and _e()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these theme strings are prepared for translation and the theme is not in english by default  (they're outputed with `__()` or `_e()` functions) and you include your theme textdomain correctly, then you probably haven't translated these strings to english.

WPML had/has some tool to do this, but it isn't very user-friendly (at least I don't like this tool). I'd suggest using [Codestyling Localization plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/).

Install it, rescan your theme directory (it will find all translation strings) and then add missing translations. Don't forget to build `.mo` files after translating strings (without it new translations won't work).

EDIT:
It occured that it was some problem with .po/.mo files. Installing Codestyling Localization and rebuilding translation files solved this problem.

Comment: You mean, I should create a en_US.po and en_US.mo files in the theme ?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that :)

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work

Comment: OK, what exactly have you done/tried? Can you show me how these strings (one example) are outputed? Are you sure that your theme is including it's textdomain correctly?

Comment: Well you can the strings on the URLs in my first post. At the bottom, you will see larges rows with facebook and twitter links. They should be in english on the english site.

The code :
`<?php _e('Join us on Facebook', 'thevineyard'); ?>`

Is my textdomain is correct ? I think so since I see the french translation. The problem is I do not see the original english text (as it is in the code)

Comment: OK, so these strings are written in english in PHP files? And when you go to english version of your site, they're translated to french?

Comment: Exactly. This is the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9324/discussion-between-krzysiek-drozdz-and-pauletienney)

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż creating en_US language files is not necessary, by default WordPress is in US English.

Comment: @Piet WordPress is in english. But theme doesn't have to be in english by default.

Comment: Ahhh, and yes - it was problem with .po/.mo files in the end, so my intuition was right in this case ;)

Comment: theme doesn't have to be in English, but in 99.9% of the cases it actually is

Comment: In 99,9% of cases? Base on your experience or on free themes? Based on my experience with custom themes it's not like that at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may come from a wrong locale.
Try to look at the [WPML > Localisation](http://wpml.org/fr/documentation-6/guide-de-demarrage-rapide/localisation-de-theme/) menu to check that the locale file names are correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that your default language is set to French and your secondary language is set to English, correct?

Then you will need to go to WPML > String Translation and scroll down to the bottom where the metabox "Original language of strings" has been located. Most likely your Strings Language there has been set to French, which is wrong and should be English.

Also make sure that you have installed a default (US English) WordPress version and that you have left the WPLANG definition (in your wp-config.php) alone, i.e. `define ( 'WPLANG', '' );`

Comment: Why do you think that installing US English version of WordPress is important? The only difference between these versions is translation files they contain. WordPress already knows which translation files to use (you can put all of them in your WP installation and it won't be a problem).

Comment: I don't "think" it is important, this is the *only* way to properly set up WPML on your site.

Comment: Language of WordPress zip package has no impact on translation plugins at all. Take a look at differences between these packages - it will be obvious then...

Comment: Let's agree to disagree, you do it your way and I do it mine.